Total differential of a composite function

Let $w=f(u)$. Determine $dw$, if $u=x^2+xy+y^2+z^2-3x+5y-2z$

I found that $\ du = (2x + y - 3) dx + (x + 2y + 5)dy + (2z - 2)dz .$ Assuming $ dw = \frac{\partial w}{\partial u} du,$ I obtained:
$$
dw = \frac{\partial w}{\partial u} \ du = \frac{\partial w}{\partial u}( (2x + y - 3) dx + (x + 2y + 5)dy + (2z - 2)dz) .
$$
Is this correct? Is it sufficient? Is there anything else I should do next?

Where is $f$ in your answer ?

@Digitallis Isn't $\partial w$ enough?

@Digitallis I'm sorry I don't understand where to place f

Your expression for $du$ is correct. What you write for $dw$ is acceptable but I would probably replace $\partial w/\partial u$ by $f'(u),.$
